# Java Runtime different versions on windows

Tags: java

I have installed 2 different versions of Java on my Windows 7 64-bit. One version 6 and another version 7.

One app that i run from http, seems using version 7, though i want it to be version 6.

How can I change the path to use version 6? Please note i am technical but not on oracle..so maybe a step by step could be useful.

Comment: You want to set the version of the Java Plug-in in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Change you `JAVA_HOME` to 7 version also you need to update the `Path` variable if it is hard coded like `c:\Program Files\java\bin` .